# How to get the unique list of elements from a map values

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Set<Map<String, Object>>`. The elements have been given below:

```
final Set<Map<String, Object>> set = new HashSet<>();
        final Map<String, Object> objectMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap1.put("name", "Sourav");
        objectMap1.put("class", 10);
        objectMap1.put("city", "London");
        objectMap1.put("Department", "Science");

        final Map<String, Object> objectMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap2.put("name", "Sourav");
        objectMap2.put("class", 10);
        objectMap2.put("city", "Kolkata");
        objectMap2.put("Department", "Science");

        final Map<String, Object> objectMap3 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap3.put("name", "Wills");
        objectMap3.put("class", 9);
        objectMap3.put("city", "Peterborough");
        objectMap3.put("Department", "Java");

        final Map<String, Object> objectMap4 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap4.put("name", "Wills");
        objectMap4.put("class", 9);
        objectMap4.put("city", "Manchester");
        objectMap4.put("Department", "Java");

        set.add(objectMap1);
        set.add(objectMap2);
        set.add(objectMap3);
        set.add(objectMap4);
```

As per the above example, a student can reside in two cities.

I want a final list of StudentBuilder where each element of a list will have list of citities.

Expected output: [{ "name": Sourav, "city": [London, Kolkata], "Department", "Science", "Standard": 10 }, { "name": Wills, "city": [Manchester, Peterborough], "Department", "Java", "Standard": 9 } ]

I have done it in the below way, but I used two loops which is not good performance wise. Can we make it in a single loop?
Constraints: StudentBuilder can not be modified. It's immutable and a third party jar.

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<Map<String, Object>> set = new HashSet<>();
        final Map<String, Object> objectMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap1.put("name", "Sourav");
        objectMap1.put("class", 10);
        objectMap1.put("city", "London");
        objectMap1.put("Department", "Science");

        final Map<String, Object> objectMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap2.put("name", "Sourav");
        objectMap2.put("class", 10);
        objectMap2.put("city", "Kolkata");
        objectMap2.put("Department", "Commerce");

        final Map<String, Object> objectMap3 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap3.put("name", "Wills");
        objectMap3.put("class", 10);
        objectMap3.put("city", "Peterborough");
        objectMap3.put("Department", "Computer");

        final Map<String, Object> objectMap4 = new HashMap<>();
        objectMap4.put("name", "Wills");
        objectMap4.put("class", 9);
        objectMap4.put("city", "Manchester");
        objectMap4.put("Department", "Java");

        set.add(objectMap1);
        set.add(objectMap2);
        set.add(objectMap3);
        set.add(objectMap4);

        final Map<String, List<String>> locationGroupsByStudent = new HashMap<>();
        set.forEach(a -> {
            locationGroupsByStudent.computeIfAbsent((String)a.get("name"), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add((String)a.get("city"));
        });

        final List<StudentBuilder> studentList = set.stream()
            .filter(d -> locationGroupsByStudent.containsKey(d.get("name")))
            .map(d -> {
                final List<String> locationGroupNames = locationGroupsByStudent.get(d.get("name"));
                locationGroupsByStudent.remove(d.get("name"));
                return StudentBuilder.builder()
                    .name((String)d.get("name"))
                    .cities(locationGroupNames)
                    .department((String)d.get("Department"))
                    .standard((Integer)d.get("class"))
                    .build();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

Comment: Do not deal with `Object`, and move to a concrete type. Define your own to make it much readable and type bound.

Comment: So you are asking to modify the data type of Set? How can this make sure the number of calls will be reduced

Comment: No, I was asking you to move away from `Set<Map<String, Object>>` to  a `Set<Student> students` as assumed in the answer provided.

Comment: Note that your `forEach` calling `computeIfAbsent` is equivalent to a `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(…` operation. You can use it to construct a `StudentBuilder` in the first place, if it has a method to add cities rather than provide a complete list via `cities(…)`. If it requires a complete list, there is no way around collecting them first and providing the result in a second operation.